# Running queries in SQL while big stored-procedure is executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, silverlight, stored-procedures

I have a situation where I need to run a stored procedure (>5mins) and want my (silverlight) application to remain 'alive'

This I do with an async WCF Service for my UI thread to be responsive, at least until I request some data from the same DB again

Then, only after SP is finished the other request are executed

Can I somehow (in SQL I suppose) set the storedprocedure to be able to run alongside with other queries?

Thanks

**edit:**

1. DB is on SQL Server
2. starting SP from Linq2Sql model in `[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]` service method
3. other data is handled with WCF Ria Services (DomainService from Linq2SQL model, same connection string)

**edit 2:**

@dan1111: With testing I saw that until the point when WCF service returns result to Silverlight, DomainContext 'freezes'

Initially:

1. I call WCF Async method with Thread.Sleep(15000)
2. Application continues to work good
3. When I go to a page where data is needed, I request DataContext.Load()
4. DataContext.IsLoading becomes true
5. I must wait the remaining of the 15seconds
6. Now the completed event is fired for the previous DataContext.Load

Please tell me your opinion

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Execute the stored procedure using another connection than your 'alive' queries.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution is to open more than one connection to the database.  Each connection can do its own stuff.

However, there is another way to do it that actually sets up a procedure to run asynchronously:

http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

Comment: @dvox, I can't tell from the information you have provided whether it is a code issue or a database issue.  The second connection needs to be used in a separate thread in your code; i.e. it needs to be running asynchronously.

Comment: what do you mean by 'separate thread'? 
On client side (silverlight): call to the service starts in a separate thread
On server side: The connection is created inside the service method

Comment: @dvox, you will need two threads on the server side--one for each connection to the database.